LED image phase projection
Say you have a goal image G with a phase called phase G. Can you physically construct and project phase G, or is phase not something physical? Like, can you set up an array of LEDs to project the phase of an image onto glass, ie, or is that idea nonsense? I am thinking of the case where you get the DFT of phase G, and how you can represent it as a plot picture. My bigger question is whether you can computationally generate phase G of images, project that onto a clear surface, and use the magnitude of light of external objects to obtain a worse version of images G.

What do you mean by "phase of an image"? Are you talking about the phase of its complex 2D Discrete Fourier Transform ?

Yes, I mean the phase of a 2D image’s complex DFT. I saw in a signal processing class that you can reconstruct an image by using the just its DFT phase + the DFT magnitude of a different arbitrary image.
